# Call an SQL query record with foreach

Tags: php, sql, foreach

I want to call a record from SQL:

```
$up_recs = $db->get_results("SELECT RID,note FROM notes"); 
if ($up_recs > NULL)
    { 
    foreach($up_recs as $rec)
        { 
          echo $rec['note']."<br/>";          
        } 
    }
```

and have a error:

Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

????

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
echo $rec->note."<br/>";
```

instead of

```
echo $rec['note']."<br/>";
```